# On whether there exists $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\phi(e_1), \phi(e_2) \neq 0$ but $\phi^{2} (e_1) = 0 = \phi^{2} (e_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> For any $\phi \in \text{Hom}(V,V)$, let $\phi^2 = \phi \circ \phi$. Does there exist $\phi \in \text{Hom}(V,V)$ such that $\phi(e_1) \neq 0$ and $\phi(e_2) \neq 0$ yet $\phi^{2} (e_1) = \phi^{2} (e_2) = 0$?

I believe that the answer is no, but I came to this conclusion in a rather heavy-handed manner. I wrote out the matrix of $\phi$ relative to the standard basis with entries $a,b,c,d$, where it was required that no two entries of the same column could be $0$. Multiplying this matrix by itself gave the zero matrix and hence a system of equations. Two of the equations featured a square of one of the coefficients plus another linear term, so the coefficient squared must be $0$. After repeating this, I found a contradiction that one of the entire columns must be $0$.

With that said, I can't figure out how to prove this with only linear transformations -- without choosing a basis -- which seems ideal. I think I should proceed by contradiction and suppose there existed such a $\phi$. Then $\phi^{2} (e_1) = \phi(\phi(e_1)) = 0$, so $\phi(e_1)$ is a non-trivial element of the kernel of $\phi$. That tells me that $\phi$ cannot be injective nor surjective, so the columns of the matrix representation have to be linearly dependent. I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed, though.

I'd appreciate any hints or guidance on how to proceed. I'll update this question as I work on this problem more.

Comment: This matrix $\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The conditions $\phi^2(e_1)=\phi^2(e_2)$ together mean that $\phi^2=0$, since $e_1,e_2$ form a basis. So you are looking for a $2\times 2$ matrix, with both columns nonzero, that squares to zero. This is easily achieved. For instance we can take $$\psi=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix},$$ which satisfies $\psi^2=0$, and change basis with some invertible matrix. Like
$$
\phi=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&5\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 5&-2\\ -2&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\ 0&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 5&-2\\ -2&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2&1\\ -4&2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Of course, any other invertible matrix also works.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm a bit confused, though, on the matrix $\psi$ which sends $e_1$ to $0$. Why does a chance of basis guarantee that $e_1$ is sent elsewhere? I thought this was determined by the transformation, rather than the matrix/choice of basis.

Comment: I have to admit I don't really understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

We want $\Phi^2=0$ and $\Phi(e_i) \neq 0$. Therefore the only eigenvalue is $0$. Let $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ the matrix of $\Phi$. The characteristic polynomial is $\det \Phi + X^2 - (\text{tr}\Phi) X$ and should be $X^2$, so $\det \Phi = 0$ and $a+d = \text{tr} \Phi = 0$. This means precisely, that $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = \mu \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & \lambda^2  \\ -1 & -\lambda \end{pmatrix}$ for some $\mu,\lambda \neq 0$.